# Do we know how much energy is released in internal conversion (fluorescence)?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, photons, fluorescence

In the Jablonski Diagram, when photons hit a surface and certain frequencies are absorbed, then internal conversion occurs to the excited portions of the surface and energy is released as heat (If I understand the process correctly, please correct me if I'm wrong).

[image]

What I want to know is how much energy is released as heat (or an estimate), and/or if there has been research conducted on the subject, because I haven't found much research on the quantity of energy released in internal conversion.